# Mailchimp single user view

Tags: mailchimp

Is it possible to get a view of a user's activity (opens, clicks etc) via the Mailchimp API?

Looking through the docs, it seems possible at the campaign level, but I would like to see this information across all campaigns for a given user.

Answer (score 1):

I think that Member-activity could be closed to what you want, I am not aware of any other direct method how to get this.

check API [MailChimp API - Lists section](http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/2.0/lists/member-activity.php)

Comment: In mailchimp v3, the link is here: http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/lists/members/activity/